# Removing attention layer from decoder model

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning

I have this encoder-decoder model and I want to remove the attention layer.

Encoder:

```
class Encoder(Model):
    def __init__(self,embed_dim):
        super(Encoder, self).__init__()
        self.dense = tf.keras.layers.Dense(embed_dim) #build your Dense layer with relu activation
        
    def call(self, features):
        features =  self.dense(features) # extract the features from the image shape: (batch, 8*8, embed_dim)
        features =  tf.keras.activations.relu(features, alpha=0.01, max_value=None, threshold=0)
        return features
```

Decoder:

```
class Decoder(Model):
    def __init__(self, embed_dim, units, vocab_size):
        super(Decoder, self).__init__()
        self.units=units
        self.W1 = tf.keras.layers.Dense(units) 
        #self.attention = Attention_model(self.units) #iniitalise your Attention model with units
        self.embed = tf.keras.layers.Embedding(vocab_size, embed_dim) #build your Embedding layer
        self.gru = tf.keras.layers.GRU(self.units,return_sequences=True,return_state=True,recurrent_initializer='glorot_uniform')
        self.d1 = tf.keras.layers.Dense(self.units) #build your Dense layer
        self.d2 = tf.keras.layers.Dense(vocab_size) #build your Dense layer
        
    def call(self,x,features, hidden):
        context_vector, attention_weights = self.attention(features, hidden) #create your context vector & attention weights from attention model
        embed = self.embed(x) # embed your input to shape: (batch_size, 1, embedding_dim)
        embed = tf.concat([tf.expand_dims(context_vector, 1), embed], axis = -1)  # Concatenate your input with the context vector from attention layer. Shape: (batch_size, 1, embedding_dim + embedding_dim)
        output,state = self.gru(embed) # Extract the output & hidden state from GRU layer. Output shape : (batch_size, max_length, hidden_size)
        output = self.d1(output)
        output = tf.reshape(output, (-1, output.shape[2])) # shape : (batch_size * max_length, hidden_size)
        output = self.d2(output) # shape : (batch_size * max_length, vocab_size)
      
        return output, state #, attention_weights
    
    def init_state(self, batch_size):
        return tf.zeros((batch_size, self.units))
```

Attention:

```
class Attention_model(Model):
    def __init__(self, units):
        super(Attention_model, self).__init__()
        self.W1 = tf.keras.layers.Dense(units) 
        self.W2 = tf.keras.layers.Dense(units) 
        self.V = tf.keras.layers.Dense(1) 
        self.units=units

    def call(self, features, hidden):
        hidden_with_time_axis = hidden[:, tf.newaxis]
        score = tf.keras.activations.tanh(self.W1(features) + self.W2(hidden_with_time_axis))  
        attention_weights = tf.keras.activations.softmax(self.V(score), axis=1) 
        context_vector = attention_weights * features 
        context_vector = tf.reduce_sum(context_vector, axis=1)  
        return context_vector, attention_weights
```

How to connect encoder output with decoder input after removing the attention layer?